# MySQL error max user online

Tags: mysql

What's bad?

```
public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database)
    {    
        $this->_connection = mysql_pconnect($host, $user, $password) or die( mysql_error( ) );
        if ( !$this->_connection )
        {
            throw new Exception(mysql_error( ));

    }
    mysql_select_db( $database, $this->_connection );
    if ( mysql_error() )
    {
        throw new Exception(mysql_error( ) );
        }

    }
```

If I have more than 20 users online, I have error max_user_online ...

Comment: You're using `mysql_pconnect()` which opens a persistent connection, so you're quickly exceeding the maximum. Use `mysql_connect()` so that the connection are dropped once each page is loaded. Note that `mysql_*()` is deprecated, so you should be using `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Presumably, there is a configuration item for the maximum number of concurrent users, and the name is `max_user_online` and the limit is set to `20` and you need to increase it (and, in all probability, restart MySQL).

Comment: Warning:  User goplt_muizika already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in ....
User goplt_muizika already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections